# applying function to a series of items in a list of lists

Tags: r, apply

I have a function that needs to be applied to the same item in a list which is in a list pool. it is as follows:

```
myFUN<-function(x) { 

myRESULT<-sqrt(sd(x)/50)

return(myRESULT)
}
```

i need to apply `myFUN` to a list such as:

`big.list[[i]][["smaller.list"]][["smallest.list"]]`

here, the thing is that there are 1500 different `i` in `big.list` and each of them have `smaller.list` and `smallest.list` in them. in other words, `smallest.list` is a list in `smaller.list` while `smaller.list` is a list in `i` and `i` is a list in `big.list`. also `i`s are numbers from 1 to 1500.

I need to apply `myFUN` to each of the `i`s and get the mean of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to loop through the `list`, extract the smaller.list and smallest.list, apply the function. and then get the `mean`

```
mean(sapply(big.list, function(x) myFUN(x[["smaller.list"]][["smallest.list"]])))
```

Comment: I guess it is lapply and there is a comma after big.list? if so, i need the mean of the result which is also another problem for me

Comment: @jimmyquidd  sorry a typo.  I meeant `sapply` to return a `vector` and then get the `mean`

Comment: yeah, that works. but above in your first comment,  it is still sappy, instead of sapply. thx anyways :)